# How to protect against password loss?

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-recovery

I'm running a well encrypted multiple backed up password database. How do I make sure that in a catastrophic event let's say I have a car crash and can't remember the master password, I and only I can regain access to my database?

Comment: I filed the password to my password manager and the login to my main computer with my Will.   That works just fine.